# Iniciante - Passando um arquivo em Python com seu conteudo como argumento

Tags: python, script, hash

Olá,
Estou aprendendo Python, sou bem iniciante e meu objetivo com este script é:

1. Pegar o conteudo do arquivo wl.txt, ler linha a linha e usar com o comando crypt.crypt
2. Comparar a hash gerada com um salt já definido e comparar esta com uma hash que declarei dentro do arquivo.
3. Se o resultado da hash for igual ao hash que eu defini dentro do arquivo, que apareça a mensagem "Senha Encontrada"

Segue meu codigo:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
    import crypt
    import sys
    
    #       The password is 123456789 and the salt $1$1234$
    #       Hash $1$1234$iePzeiQ11EHTph.AjL0GM.
    
    hash = r"$1$1234$iePzeiQ11EHTph.AjL0GM."
    salt = r"$1$1234$"
    
    with open('wl.txt') as file:
            for password in file.readlines():
                    print ("Trying ...: %s" %(password))
                    newhash = crypt.crypt(password, salt)
                    print newhash
    
                    if (newhash == hash):
                            print ("Password found: %s" %(password))
                    else:
                            print "Password not found!"
```

Saida:

```
┌──(nag㉿kali)-[~]
└─$ python2 hash.py
Trying ...: 123456

$1$1234$8acUSdjZh2kFpS8HkRvvD1
Password not found!
Trying ...: aaa

$1$1234$anGF2igSbkWXaDyzTS3PS.
Password not found!
Trying ...: bbb

$1$1234$PHMaanM3Bt1Xuq8nx0eDu/
Password not found!
Trying ...: ccc

$1$1234$UyV97kO.cYwUbb3aC3x9d.
Password not found!
Trying ...: ddd

$1$1234$Ej0sL587fdyknWC7zJBrG/
Password not found!
Trying ...: eee

$1$1234$7fNlaEimk/x0WCNcHpkIi.
Password not found!
Trying ...: 123456789

$1$1234$MwVqxKiIuhUo7IeS3fMCt0
Password not found!
```

Obrigado a todos que puderem ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que você ao ler as linhas está a incluir o caratér de nova linha. Se ler assim já funciona.

```
for password in file.read().splitlines():
```